# optimal binning in R

Tags: r, spss, predictive-models, binning

SPSS has an optimal binning function that helps categorizing into meaningful intervals continuous predictors when a binary response variable exists. I was looking for an equivalent function in R but I'm not finding any. I'm not sure that using bins derived by CART or CTREE could be equivalent.

Comment: In practice very, very few people know both SPSS and R in any depth. I think you would need to be much more precise what this "optimal binning" is to get an answer. That aside, binning a continuous predictor is widely deprecated as very poor statistical practice, in my view fairly. http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous is a good introduction. In addition, "optimal binning" (not your name, presumably) is a loaded term!

Comment: See also e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable in this forum.

Comment: I agree that restricted cubic splines or non parametric smoothers takes better into account non - linearity. Nevertheless the algorithm that this analysis will derive cannot make use of such smoothers.

Comment: There is a `cut` function and in documentation of `?hist` you can find info about algorithms that choose "optimal" number of bins for histogram. See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163778/how-do-you-find-a-cutting-point-strong-slope-within-one-dimensional-data/163787#163787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the discretization package and the cutPoints function : http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/discretization/discretization.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a package call "smbinning" that longs for Optimal Binning for Scoring Modeling since early 2015. It gives you the optimal cut point for a numeric variable, more precisely, optimizing the information value. It is able to handle categorical variable and missing value as well.

For example:

```
smbinning(df, y , x, p = 0.05)
```

- df <- Data frame
- y <- Binary dependent variable
- x <- numeric independent variable
- p <- Percentage of records per bin

It returns a list that contains the information value, Information value table and others. you may find detail in the documentation at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smbinning/smbinning.pdf) or [http://www.scoringmodeling.com/](http://www.scoringmodeling.com/rpackage/smbinning/)

Comment: To be honest not the biggest fan of the smbinning package. I haven't coded anything better but the coding in the package feels "amateurish", and it fails in many of the test cases I tried. I don't recommend smbinning at v0.2.